# NSTimeIntervalSinceDate gives 86,399 seconds between consecutive days, why?

Tags: ios, nstimeinterval

In iOS, Xcode9, and Obj-C, I am trying to find out how much time has elapsed in days between two dates.  I know the NSTimeIntervalSince method yields a result in seconds.  But it seems that when I calculate the seconds between consecutive days (like 11-2-2016 and 11-3-2016), I am 1 second short, yielding 86,399.  If I calculate seconds between larger intervals, I am always a second short.

11-2-2016 to 11-4-2016: 172,799 (two 24-hour days but missing a second)

11-2-2016 to 11-5-2016: 259,199 (three 24-hour days but missing a second)

Here's my code:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate *firstDate; 
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate *secondDate;

@synthesize firstDate, secondDate;

int secondsIntervalFirstDatetoSecondDate = (fabs([firstDate timeIntervalSinceDate:secondDate]));
NSLog(@"seconds between firstDate and secondDate %i", secondsIntervalFirstDatetoSecondDate);
```

firstDate and secodDate are NSDate
They are entered by the user using a datePicker and date formatting is set as

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];
```

I've searched for an answer but could find none.
First post for a newbie, sorry for any etiquette errors, I'll try to improve.

Comment: Hard to say. Post the code that creates your date objects.

Comment: (BTW, if you're a newbie why are you programming in Objective-C? Just about all new development is being done in Swift.)

Comment: ^Might be new to StackOverflow but working on an old project.. @OP: https://pastebin.com/UiC6Zp3b this prints `259200.0`.. You might have a formatting issue or rounding issue somewhere.. somehow..

Comment: @DuncanC and others:  I just edited post to show my creation of the objects.  I suspect I need to show you more code than that, but not sure.  You folks can tell me...

Comment: @DuncanC and others:  new to StackOverflow, sorta new to software development, I've been dabbling in iOS apps since 2010.  It's hard enough to work in Obj-C, so moving to Swift would double my incompetence!  I learned coding in the 1980's.  I'm a full time physician.  Apps for physicians and trainees is my hobby and my contribution to my field.  I'd love to quit my day job and learn programming in depth.  But I might not be very good at it, and I kinda like and need my day job.

Comment: Show the code that creates `firstDate` and `secondDate`. Also show how you're configuring your date picker objects.

Comment: What is your actual *goal*? As Rob says, you shouldn't assume that a day has 86,400 seconds in it, or that the difference between 2 dates will always be a fixed number of seconds. Tell us what you are trying to do and we'll help you accomplish it.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a `UIDatePicker` and put it in "date" mode, the time is the time the date picker was created. If you're creating two pickers, they're going to be created at slightly different times. Even a very small difference in those times can lead to a 1-second difference.

You should never compute time-differences this way. [There are not 86,400 seconds in a day.](http://yourcalendricalfallacyis.com) "How many days are between two points in time" is complicated, and you should use the tools designed for it: `NSDateComponents` and `NSCalendar`.

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar calendarWithIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSInteger diffInDays = [[calendar components:NSCalendarUnitDay 
                                    fromDate:[calendar startOfDayForDate:date1]
                                      toDate:[calendar startOfDayForDate:date2] 
                                     options:0] day];
```

Comment: Interesting that date pickers in date mode register the moment in time when they were created. I didn't know that. Another comment: The OP makes mention of Date strings and date formatters. It isn't clear where date formatters fit into this problem (aside from displaying the resulting date values.) You should use date components to convert between dates and month/day/year values as well.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not clear on the involvement of date formatters either. And yeah, if you're doing any computation at all that involves the words "day," "month," or "year" you have to use date components.

Comment: I just did a little research and found that a `UIDatePicker` set to date mode *defaults* to returning dates who's time value is the moment of the picker's creation, but that you can override that behavior. You can set the date picker to an arbitrary Date (using its date property) and it then uses the time of that date as the time value it returns.

Comment: I wrote code in my view controller's `viewDidLoad()` method that gets month/day/year date components from the current date, then converts those DateComponents back to a date (effectively giving you a Date of exactly midnight today.) The date picker will then always return a Date who's time value is midnight regardless of the date the user picks.

Comment: @RobNapier This technique seems promising.  The only other things I do in my app are move forward in time or backwards in time from one date to another by integer numbers of days.  From the example above with an 'NSInteger diffInDays', how would I start with a NSDate 'startingDate' and add or subtract 'diffInDays' to move forward or backward in time to arrive at 'endingDate'?

Comment: Study the docs for `NSCalendar`. There are many date manipulation methods to perform date math, including adding a specific number of days.